# Configuring Spring MVC and Vaadin in context hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vaadin

I am looking for any ideas or PoC on how to integrate (specifically configure) Spring MVC and Vaadin (Framework 8) in one web application; preferably as a context hierarchy.

The use case is the Vaadin application as the root context "/" and the Spring MVC application on some other context "/m" (which will be used for server mobile-friendly views).

I have not been able to find any examples, partial or fully, that shows how this is achieved in the configuration (Spring Boot) and I'm constantly running into various problems with invalid context loading, unmapped MVC view references etc. depending on the examples I'm running.

I've looked into this from the perspective of this line in the [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/#_bootstrapping_a_vaadin_spring_application), but have simply not found anything on these topics I can combine to make a solution.

> It is possible to map both DispatcherServlet and SpringVaadinServlet to different context paths to use both simultaneously to e.g. support Spring MVC and Vaadin in the same application. If doing so, remember to also map the path “/VAADIN/*” to the Vaadin servlet for serving static resources.

Comment: Properties is responsible for this `vaadin.servlet.url-mapping`, just define it in spring application.properties. For other settings check [VaadinServletConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/boot/internal/VaadinServletConfigurationProperties.java)

Comment: @borino That is only the path of the Vaadin app, though. What I'm having problems with is how to configure the app so that both Vaddin and Spring MVC is running (on different paths).